# Does David not understand that humans can't live that long?

Tags: ai-artificial-intelligence

In the movie *AI: Artificial Intelligence*, they say David's mom is dead because 2000 years have passed. Does David not understand that humans can't live that long?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sci-Fi, great first question. Please take the time to read out [tour] and check out some other questions, to familiarise yourself with the site.

Answer (score 4):

**David doesn't understand.** His perception is intentionally that of a child ("*You were created to be so young*") and he has no obvious conception of mortality, only a persistent and unwavering hard-wired love for Monica.

- He doesn't realise that he's spent more time in the hovercopter than her lifespan. He seems to think it was a single long day (possibly because he's basing his idea of time on sleep cycles).

> **DAVID:** Will Mommy be coming home soon? Is she out shopping with Martin now?
>
> [and]
>
> **DAVID:** Maybe the one day will be like that one day inside the amphibicopter, maybe it will last forever.

- When he's outright told that **she's dead** and how much time has passed, he moves onto the next step in his programming, seeking solutions to the problem of being apart from Monica, as he's done throughout the entirety of his existence.

> **BLUE FAIRY:** David, she can never come home, because two-thousand years have passed, and she is no longer living. Dearest David, when you are lonely, we can bring back other people from your time in the past.
>
> **DAVID:** If you can bring back other people, why can’t you bring back HER?